# How to trigger multiple builds on a gerrit commit?

Tags: gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have gerrit project integrated with Jenkins Server.

When i push a commit into gerrit then a jenkins build is triggered for windows OS(configured parameter) only. Now i want the gerrit to trigger a build on linux OS as well.

So how do we configure such that a commit into gerrit triggers two builds one on Windows OS and the other one on Linux OS ?

Could anyone suggest on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Gerrit trigger pulugin in your job in Jenkins. You can read more detail on this link: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger
Actually this plugin checks the Gerrit events so you can trigger many job with one commit. I use this Plugin to trigger more jobs in Jenkins and it works as expected.